# Pass through JSON with Servicestack

Tags: json, servicestack

I want to give a JSON response where one of the fields simply contains a JSON string from another source. (I'm using PostGIS to return a set of GeoJSON strings for a feature.) I've verified that PostGIS responds with the correct JSON, store it as a string and then want to pass it to the response object.

Is there any way I can make the Servicestack response object simply include this piece of JSON directly into its JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `RawSerializeFn` which allows you to attach your own serialization method to an object.

### Method:

I would create an object called `RawJsonData` like this:

```
public class RawJsonData
{
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
    public RawJsonData(string json)
    {
        JsonData = json;
    }
}
```

Then in your application config call this command to attach the custom serializer:

```
JsConfig<RawJsonData>.RawSerializeFn = c=> c.JsonData;
```

That simply returns the data in `JsonData` as the raw Json.

### Usage:

In your response object, simply create a `RawJsonData` object and populate it's value. Then when it is serialized, it will serialize the raw data.

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public RawJsonData MyJson { get; set; } // My contents will serialize raw!
    ...
    public string NormalStringValue { get; set; } // Normal string
    public int NormalIntValue { get; set; }
}

var response = new MyResponse { MyJson = new RawJsonData("YOUR RAW JSON HERE"), /* Other Values etc */ };
```

I hope that helps.